# How to code to fill down a range with the above value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro where in column B I need to fill and copy down the value above until the next value is found and again it is copied down until the next one and so and so.

Right now I have the following syntaxis:

```
Range("B:B").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
```

It is working, but the "currentregion" is creating some data that I do not want. How can I replace that or change my syntaxis to make it work only in column B:B

Answer (score 0):

First things first, be careful with `Range("B:B").CurrentRegion` - it will not necessarily include everything in column B as my example below shows.  Next, this macro will copy cell values down to empty cells.  `Application.ScreenUpdating` will speed it up if the range is large.

```
Sub CopyDown()

Dim rAll, r As Range

Set rAll = Range("B:B").CurrentRegion
Set r = Range("B2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
While Not Intersect(r, rAll) Is Nothing             ' ie. r in the "current region"
    If IsEmpty(r) Then r.Value = r.Offset(-1).Value ' copy down the value above
    Set r = r.Offset(1)                             ' move down 1 row
Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image: pear never reaches orange]